# Twitter counter display random number

Tags: twitter, blogger

I've just added the Twitter button on my [blog](http://www.zombiekb.com) under each post, but the tweets number displayed is the same on each button and is random.

In addition to this, if I enter to a post the number displayed change :S

Any idea about this issue?

EDIT:

This is the code that I'm actually using for the Twitter button

```
<a class='twitter-share-button' data-count='horizontal'data-lang='it'
data-via='ZOMBIEKB' expr:data-text='data:post.title'
expr:data-url='data:post.url' href='https://twitter.com/share'>Tweet</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)
[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=&
quot;//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js&quot;;fjs.parentNode.insertBefore
(js,fjs);}}(document,&quot;script&quot;,&quot;twitter-wjs&quot;);</script>
```

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and suggest that the Twitter button probably works in general, so the problem is in your code. So, maybe post your code?

Comment: Original question edited adding the code :) ....thank you for you patience :)

Answer (score 0):

Each widgets `data-url` has to point to the url of the post it is describing not yout blog url:

yes: `data-url="http://www.zombiekb.com/url-to-this-post/"`

no: `data-url="http://www.zombiekb.com/"`